# How to clear all session variables without getting logged out

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-sessions

I am trying to clear all of the session variables but not logout the current user.

```
user = request.session.get('member_id', None)
request.session.flush()
request.session.modified = True
request.session['member_id'] = user
request.session.modified = True
```

Will this also affect other users of the site?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Django 1.8, any call to `flush()` will log out the user. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush):

> Changed in Django 1.8: Deletion of the session cookie is a behavior
>   new in Django 1.8. Previously, the behavior was to regenerate the
>   session key value that was sent back to the user in the cookie.

If you want to be able to delete keys but keep the user logged in, you'll need to handle it manually:

```
for key in request.session.keys():
    del request.session[key]
```

Or just delete the specific keys that are of concern:

```
del request.session['mykey']
```

Comment: I get an error:     for key in request.session.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration. Fix below.

Comment: @AdamG Gather your keys in a list, then delete them on mass.  This is pretty typical error when mutating an iterable that you're currently iterating through.

Comment: Alternative: Gather the credentials you need to keep the user logged in in a dict, session.flush(), then loop over the dict and put it back in session.

Answer (score 15):

In versions of django < 1.8, [`session.flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) deletes the session data and regenerates the session key. It won't affect other users since session keys are unique.

Comment: it's only in django 1.8 +?

Comment: it's been there since at least 1.3

Comment: don't get why I don't see the methods on a Session object in console?
I'm fetching it through Session.objects.get(session_key=...)

Comment: Because that's not the same as a `request.session` object. If you want to use sessions outside of a view use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views instead of the `Session` model.

Answer (score 6):

You can clear keys you have set in the django session, but to do so without logging the user out takes a little bit of trickiness; `request.session.flush()` logs the user out. And `request.session = {}`  in deleting all keys in the session dictionary will also log the user out.

Thus, to clear out keys without logging the user out, you have to avoid keys that begin with an underscore character. The following code does the trick:

```
for key in list(request.session.keys()):
  if not key.startswith("_"): # skip keys set by the django system
    del request.session[key]
```

Answer (score 5):

As an improvement to shacker's[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688199/4756514) in Python 2.x `dict.keys()` returns a list copy of the keys of a dictionary, in Python 3.x it instead returns an iterator. changing the size of an iterator is unwise. For an version safe implementation casting to list will prevent any size issues

```
for key in list(request.session.keys()):
    del request.session[key]
```

My previous answer suggested the use of `dict.viewkeys()` but it will also return an iterator in python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

`request.session` internally uses cookies. And when a user requests some url of the site, only cookies present on that user's machine is sent to the server. So, `request.session` is always tied to the current user.

So, this in no way will affect other users of the site.

Also this will not log out the current user, because you are using `flush()` which will delete the old session and create a new session and this new session would be associated with the current user.

`flush()` internally uses `clear()`, `delete()` and `create()`.

In the response this new session's key would be sent as a cookie and in subsequent requests this new session would continue working normally.

Comment: So why am getting logged out when I call request.session.flush()

Answer (score 2):

```
session_keys = list(request.session.keys())
    for key in session_keys:
        del request.session[key]
```