# Django session timeout issue

Tags: python, django, session

I have implemented django-session-timeout using the following library. Timeout has been configured for 900 seconds. A session timeout page is displayed when after 900 seconds of inactivity.
The problem I am facing is, whenever user opens the link for second time, a session timeout page is displayed.

Assumption: Cookies from earlier session has not been cleared.

I have tried request.session.flush() before the page loads but it doesn't work. The user is being forced to open the link twice as a temporary solution. Need a permanent solution.

Comment: Did you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688199/14457833)?

Comment: `SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT = 'your_redirect_url_here/'`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari cant delete browser cookies before loading the page

Comment: @mirodil Yes I have added the parameter in my settings.py

Comment: Hello @Tejasnayak, According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) doc. data in **sessionStorage** is cleared when the page session ends. So when you close tab and open it in new tab then you session is updated if you want you can do hard refresh. To do hard refresh **Hold down Ctrl and click the Reload button**

Comment: There is a way you can tackle this problem on page reload you can make request to check if session is expired if yes then remove session from browser cookies

Comment: Does this happen when they open a second link immediately,  or if they open a second link, for example,  a day later and you'd like them to just see a login page? If you could describe the desired behaviour that would be helpful in providing an answer

Comment: @SamSparx it happens when they open the link after 15 minutes or 900 seconds. The desired behavior is to open the login page everytime they click on the link

Comment: @AnkitTiwari can't force the user to do a hard refresh. Can you suggest how do i check whether the session has expired or not before the required page is loaded. I am using the package django-session-timeout for controlling the time out behavior.

Comment: If you remove the SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT setting, the middleware should take you to the login page by default. Is there a situation where you want to see the sesson timeout page?

Comment: @SamSparx we need to display the page during the journey if the web page is unattended for 15 minutes

Comment: Hello @Tejasnayak It will be easy for us to reproduce your problem if you can share some part of your code

Answer (score 0):

Django-session-timeout is a fairly simple piece of middleware.  It's really only one file and you can use that as the base of what you are wanting to achieve. Have a look at the [file in question](https://github.com/labd/django-session-timeout/blob/master/src/django_session_timeout/middleware.py) to see what it's doing. You can see it already uses session.flush() so that users don't see the page twice, so adding that won't help your goals.

Also, middlewhere runs before views, so the redirect will always take place if there is an expired session, regardless of how long ago that occurred.

Just to be clear, django by default won't let you *automatically* bring up an expiry page - it will only happen when you make a call to the server, eg, go to a new page so the middleware is called. Currently, from django's perspective, there's no difference between an expired user that visits a new page after 20 minutes and one that visits after 24 hours.

It sounds like what you are wanting to achieve is this:

A user visits the site, takes a break for 15 minutes, and then they get the timeout page when they next use the site.

A user visits the site, then visits the next day. This user should get the login screen.

One way to do this is to decide at what point an expired session should go to the login page.  Let's say you decide on one hour after expiry.  You can alter the middleware file (or, even better, use it as a basis of [your own middleware file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/)) and try something like this (this is based on the linked middleware file and won't work on its own):

```
    ...
    session_is_expired = time.time() - init_time > expire_seconds
    #create a new boolean variable to see if an hour has passed since expiry
    sesson_expired_hour_ago = time.time() - init_time > expire_seconds + 3600       

    
    if session_is_expired:
        #has it been less than an hour since the session expired
        if not session_expired_hour_ago:
            request.session.flush()
            redirect_url = getattr(settings, "SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT", None)
            if redirect_url:
                return redirect(redirect_url)
        #default expiry behaviour is return to login
        return redirect_to_login(next=request.path)
```

Now a user will only see the timeout page for the first hour of their expiry, and a login page afterwards.